# Using ZonedDateTime with datetimeoffset in SQLServer

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa

I have an application that uses a SQLServer database with datetimeoffset columns. Preferably, I would like to use ZonedDateTime as my JPA entity object type like so:

```
@Column(name = "CreateTimestamp", nullable = false)
ZonedDateTime createTimestamp;
```

However, the timezone is not being properly saved. No matter what I set the ZoneId to in the ZonedDateTime, the value will always be in GMT in the database.

Looking at [Microsoft's JDBC mapping diagram](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-basic-data-types), the recommended class to use is microsoft.sql.DateTimeOffset which is not what I would prefer.

I've explored using a @Converter to map between the two, but having to provide special knowledge like this seems like a red flag that I'm doing something wrong - especially since I need this to work inside of an integration test using H2.

What is the best way to use datetimeoffset and ZonedDateTime in a vendor agnostic way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question but I want to make sure the solution is documented.

The solution is to use a @Converter to transform a ZonedDateTime into a String. Hibernate will pass this down to SQLServer as a VARCHAR and the database itself will implicitly convert the value into a datetimeoffset - the same way it converts a hardcoded date when you execute a standalone query.

The following converter worked for my circumstances:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class ZonedDateTimeConverter implements AttributeConverter<ZonedDateTime, String>
{
    private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS xxx";

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime)
    {
        return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT).format(zonedDateTime);
    }

    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(String dateAsString)
    {
        return ZonedDateTime.parse(dateAsString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT));
    }
}
```

Additionally, this also works in H2 so it can be used inside of an integration test without having to do any vendor-specific logic.

Comment: The question is which version of Hibernate are you using? Recent versions do "support" `ZonedDateTime` (even though jdbc 4.2 specs does not), however with some gotchas, like you probably want to set `hibernate.jdbc.time_zone` to the timezone your database server is running with. Also the Microsoft JDBC mapping diagram you mentioned is not up to date anymore: Since version 7.1.4 the mssql-jdbc driver also supports Java's `OffsetDateTime` (instead of using `microsoft.sql.DateTimeOffset`): https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/pull/830

Answer (score 6):

A bit of a gotchya here.
The data time ZoneDateTime contains more information than an OffsetDateTime.
The zone.
Mind you, a zone is not the same as an offset. It is more.
Two zones could, at a given moment, have the same offset, but months later, one zone "springs forward" the other zone does not.
Or, they spring forward on different days.
In converting a string from an OffsetDateTime to a ZoneDateTime, you are introducing a zone where one did not exist before.

Comment: Yup, this is why DatetimeOffset is kind of useless. Really what I would want is the zone.